# how to set LIBPATH environment variable for root and bjpadm?

Tags: aix

where to set both "libpath" environment variables for root and bjpadm? my libpath they sent me is LIBPATH=/usr/lib:/lib:/usr/sap/BJP/SYS/exe/run:/usr/sap/BJP/SYS/exe/uc/rs6000_64:/oracle/client/11x_64/instantclient so how do i set up this or what file should I edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/etc/profile would be an option. You might try and make it human readable though:

```
export SAPEXEDIR=/usr/sap/BJP/SYS/exe
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/client/11x_64/instantclient
export LIBPATH=/usr/lib:$SAPEXEDIR/run:$SAPEXEDIR/uc/rs6000_64:$ORACLE_HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest /etc/environment.   On AIX, variables like PATH and LIBPATH are appropriate to set there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer I would advice to put the LIBPATH in each users .profiles if you only need this to be set for root and bjpadm.

/etc/environment and /etc/profile are system wide, and affect all users.